# bcrypt.compare return false always

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to create a login authentication for my form. I console log the passwords to check if I was doing something wrong but nothing seems to be working.
thanks!
The bcrypt.compare returns false always when it compares the result from the DB with the string password.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
            function (username, password, done) {
                User.getUserById(username, function (err, user) {
                    if (!user.length) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid Credentials! Please try again.' });
                    }
                    else {
              
                        bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password, function (err, res) {
                             return console.log(res)
                            if (err) return done(err);
                            if (res == true) {
                                User.getUserType(username, function (err, res1) {
                                    return done(null, res1[0]);
                                });
                            }
                            else {
    //                          return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid Credentials! Please try again.' });
                                return console.log("thank you, i see error")
                            }
                        });
                    }
    
    
    
    
                });
            }));
```

So return console.log(res) always gives false. Any idea on solutions?

Comment: is your "getUserById" function returning an array of users?

Comment: Are you using `mongoose` or `MongoDB` driver? cause `getUserById` is not a function, you probably mean `findById`

Comment: @matrixersp I am using MySQL DB

Comment: @Eduardo  It is meant to return the respective password in array collection of both the username and password in the database and then compare for validation

Comment: would you please check if you have bcrypt installed instead of bcryptjs

Comment: @Eduardo I actually had issues getting bcrypt so I settled for bcryptjs. Does that have any implications?